# Proving that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} < 20$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How am I suppose to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} < 20$$

Do I use the way like how we count $1+2+ \cdots+100$ to estimate?

So $1/5050 \lt 20$, implying that it is indeed less than $20$?

Comment: Ooops it's 20 not 200 typo sorry

Comment: You are falling into the trap of panicking and thinking all operations distribute.  Even without the square roots, does $\frac11 + \frac12$ have anything to do with $\frac1{1+2}$?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

We can estimate the sum by integration: because the inverse square root function is strictly descreasing, hence for $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \quad \text{ for } x\in (n-1,n).
$$
Integrating both sides on this interval:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= \int^n_{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\,dx< \int^{n}_{n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} < \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx
\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \int_1^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx
\\
\cdots
\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} < \int_{99}^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}} < \int_0^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx =20.
$$

Comment: +1 for a really amazing answer. I wouldn't have thought of that method.

Comment: The Riemann sum really _is_ good for more than just annoying first-semester calculus students with sums of powers of integers...

Comment: @Clarinetist I saw the inequality and immediately thought: hey, people always use integral to estimate the partial sum for a series, why not try on this one.

Comment: Note that a sketch makes this method a lot more intuitive!

Answer (score 44):

Start from $\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}$. Multiply top and "bottom" by $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}$.

We get $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}$, which is $\gt \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. It follows that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt 2(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})$.

Add up, $n=1$ to $n=100$. We get 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}\lt 2(\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0})+2(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})+\cdots +2(\sqrt{100}-\sqrt{99}).$$
Observe the mass cancellation on the right: it collapses to $20$.

Comment: Simply Beautiful.

Comment: "Straight from the book" :)

Answer (score 11):

A close value can be obtained easily.

Let's look at the squares until $100$:
$1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81$.
We then know that the sum will be smallar than:
$$3\cdot 1+ 5\cdot\frac{1}{2}+7\cdot\frac{1}{3}+9\cdot\frac{1}{4}+...=
\sum_{n=1}^9\frac{2n+1}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^9 2 +\frac{1}{n} =20.82$$

Comment: Very nice. If we do "exact" for the first $3$ terms, and your estimate for the rest, we get  below the target of $20$.

Comment: Beat me to it... :)  I thought something similar to the way Oresme demonstrated the _divergence_ of the harmonic series (of course, that's an _infinite_ sum) would be worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

Mean Value Theorem can also be used,

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Using mean value theorem we have:

$\displaystyle \frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n}=f'(c)$ for  some $c\in(n,n+1)$

$\displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}$....(1)

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Using the above ineq. in $(1)$ we have,

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}<\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Adding the left part of the inequality we have,$\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}<\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=\sqrt{n}-1$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=2(\sqrt{n}-1)$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<1+2\sum_{k=2}^{n}(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})=2\sqrt{n}-2+1=2\sqrt{n}-1$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}<2\sqrt{n}-1$

Similarly adding the right side of the inequality we have,

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}>\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\sqrt{n+1}-1$

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)$

Showing that,

$\displaystyle 2\sqrt{n+1}-2<\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}<2\sqrt{n}-1.\tag 1$

Put $n=100$ to prove,

$\displaystyle 2\sqrt{101}-2<\sum_{k=1}^{100}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}<2\sqrt{100}-1=19<20.$

Answer (score 2):

Note that the area under the function $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is bigger than the sum  of the retangles of bases 1 and high $f(i)$  where $i=1,\cdots,100$. so you have:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}f(i)\times 1\leq \int_{0}^{100}x^{-1/2}dx= 2(100)^{1/2}=20$$
and note that $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}f(i)\times 1=1+(2)^{-1/2}+\cdots+(100)^{-1/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int^{100}_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x} = 2\sqrt x|^{100}_1 = 2\times ( \sqrt 100 - \sqrt 1) = 18$

As, $\sum\limits^{100}_{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} < \int^{100}_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$,

So, $\sum\limits^{100}_{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt x} < 20$