# Let $p=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt {120}}$ and $q=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt {121}}$ then

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Let
> $$p=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt {120}}$$
> and
> $$q=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 4}+\cdots\frac{1}{\sqrt {121}}$$
> then which of the following is true:
> A)$\ p>20$
> B)$\ q<20$
> C)$\ p+q<40$
> D)$\ p+q>40$

The answer is ABD.

> I was able to obtain A and B, but was unable to obtain D.

**My Attempt:**

Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ when $x\in [a,a+1]$, then we have:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a+1}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt a}$$
Thus,
$$\int_a^{a+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt {a+1}}<\int_a^{a+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}< \int_a^{a+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt a}$$
Or,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt {a+1}}<\int_a^{a+1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}< \frac{1}{\sqrt a}$$
Summing the above inequality from $a=1$ to $a=120$ gives
$$q<\int_1^{121} \frac{dx}{\sqrt x}<p$$
That simplifies to $q<20<p$. But that doesn't help me comment on $p+q$.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: How much is $p-q$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust $p-q=\frac{10}{11}$, but I am still unable to see anything. Sorry for my short-sighted brain.

Comment: Use this piece of information.

Comment: @YvesDaoust (insert flushed face) I'm still unable to see anything. *Terribly* short-sighted, I am.

Comment: Combine $q<20,20<p$ and $p-q<1$.

Comment: May be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509840/use-induction-to-prove-that-1-frac-1-sqrt2-frac-1-sqrt3

Comment: @YvesDaoust Uhh, if we had $q=19.1, p-q=\frac{10}{11}$ then $p=20.0090909090\cdots$, which doesn't really fulfill $p+q>40$.

Comment: Here as sqrt(x) is a decreasing function so p>I>q. Where I is the integral of sqrt(x) from 1 to 121. Also as thr derivative of sqrt(x) is increasing, so p-I>I-q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way:

Consider trapeziums formed by the points:
$$(a,0),(a,f(a)),(a+1,0),(a+1,f(a+1))$$
for $a=1,2,....120$, and note that the sum of areas of these trapeziums is greater than $\int_1^{121} f(x) dx$. Also note that the sum of areas of the trapeziums is nothing but $\frac{p+q}{2}$. And the conclusion follows.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer so that it is more clear for future readers. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I was planning to do that later...Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
Utilize approximation
$$S(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k} \sim \frac{4n+1}{2\sqrt n}-\sqrt 2 $$

Comment: Thank you for helping, but the approximation you quote   is not in our syllabus.

Comment: He was probably using Euler-Maclaurin Summation.